# Castelnuovo-Mumford regularity and exact sequence.

Tags: commutative-algebra, exact-sequence, graded-modules

In a [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/108756/bounding-castelnuovo-mumford-regularity-in-a-short-exact-sequence) on MathOverflow it is said that:

> It is known that given a short exact sequence of finitely generated graded modules over a polynomial ring over a field:$$0 \to M'' \to M \to M' \to 0$$ then $\operatorname{reg}M\leq\max(\operatorname{reg}M',\operatorname{reg}M'').$

Unfortunately no proof is given there of the above result. Is this result obvious? Please help me to prove this.

Comment: See Eisenbud, *Commutative Algebra*, Corollary 20.19 (b).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is obvious. Take the long exact sequence of cohomology groups. Anytime, the cohomology of the two outer terms vanishes, the cohomology of the inner term will vanish, too.